# My def functions are not being executed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
print("Welcome to the BMI Index Calculator.")    
student_name = " "    
while student_name != "0":    
     student_name = input("Please begin by entering the student's name, or 0 to quit:")    
     if student_name == "0":
        print("Exiting program...")
        exit()

     def student_height():
        input("Please enter student's height in inches:")
        return

     def student_weight():
        input("Please enter student's weight in pounds:")
        return

     def bmi_profile():
        print(student_name, "'s BMI profile:")
        print("Height:", student_height, '"')
        print("Weight:", student_weight, "lbs.")

     def bmi_index(bmi):
        bmi = (student_weight * 703 / student_height ** 2)
        print("BMI Index:", bmi)
        return bmi
```

The loop runs but the def functions are not being executed. Can someone tell me where is my mistake? I try to fix the indentation many times but apparently that's not the error...
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: `def` DEFINES functions.  At no point are you actually calling them!

Comment: You're confused in how things work. Your functions are getting defined but you never call them. I'd suggest taking a tour of the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) for a nice introduction.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? It seems you want to use functions instead of create them like you are doing. Create all your functions before and put your code inside a main function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the functions first, and call them in the while loop, like this:

> Edit

I made an edit correcting all the errors you have, I will explain step by step:

First, is not necessary at all the creation of all that methods, if you create them in order to practice, it's ok, but if you don't return the data, it get loss in the cider space :D:

```
def student_height():
  return float(input("Please enter student's height in inches:")) #here you return the data

def student_weight():

  return float(input("Please enter student's weight in pounds:")) #float is used to say the type of the input, because it came as a string

def bmi_profile(name, height, weight):
  print(name, "'s BMI profile:")
  print("Height:", height, '"')
  print("Weight:", weight, "lbs.")

def bmi_index(height, weight):
  bmi = float(weight * 703 / height ** 2)
  print("BMI Index: " + str(bmi))
  return bmi


print("Welcome to the BMI Index Calculator.")    
student_name = " "    
while student_name != "0":    
  student_name = input("Please begin by entering the student's name, or 0 to quit:")
  if student_name == "0":
    print("Exiting program...")
    break

  height = student_height() #here you store the data in a variable
  weight = student_weight()
  bmi_profile(student_name, height, weight) #here you use the data stored before
  bmi_index(height, weight) #here also
```

A shorter answer:

This only two has sense... to make it a little readable

```
def bmi_profile(name, height, weight):
  print(name, "'s BMI profile:")
  print("Height:", height, '"')
  print("Weight:", weight, "lbs.")

def bmi_index(height, weight):
  bmi = float(weight * 703 / height ** 2)
  print("BMI Index: " + str(bmi))



print("Welcome to the BMI Index Calculator.")    
student_name = " "    
while student_name != "0":    
  student_name = input("Please begin by entering the student's name, or 0 to quit:")
  if student_name == "0":
    print("Exiting program...")
    break

  height = float(input("Please enter student's height in inches:"))
  weight = float(input("Please enter student's weight in pounds:"))
  bmi_profile(student_name, height, weight)
  bmi_index(height, weight)
```

Comment: This still raises errors due to `student_weight` and `student_height` not returning anything and the fact that they are being used as variable names. The question has many issues, either address them all or vote to close.

Comment: Your example is still incorrect. You are correctly calling the functions, but you aren't storing the results of the inputs in variables to operate on them later.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I am totally awared, but the question was not about it...

Comment: @reticentroot I know, but the question is not about it.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard if you want, I can edit the answer and correct all the problems, but... what will you learn if I do that?

Comment: Well, providing an answer that simply raises more errors doesn't help in reducing the confusion OP will experience, it only exacerbates it. I didn't answer this question for specifically that reason, OP doesn't need an answer on S.O telling them that they aren't calling the functions, they need a tutorial.

Comment: I understand that the question is not about that.. In that regard you are correct. But as an example it's incorrect. Let's say another beginner stumbles in here and sees this code.. You could answer the question fully and also provide a correct way to implement it. While pointing out all the mistakes the OP made in their implementation. So that it's not only an answer, but something that can be used to inform and teach...

Comment: @reticentroot okey you convinced me, I updated the answer, I think you are right

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard that's true, providing an answer with more error, it's worse, that's why I edited the answer, thanks for the feed back

Comment: Way better. I reversed my downvote to an upvote :-)

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Thanks :)